# How to save id for both nested attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what I currently get:

```
Started POST "/duels" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-15 02:51:06 -0400
Processing by DuelsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/vNueb1U+W5asQ4/Vnh5kSdeUc6uiaUKvWG1TIaAKWY0fIM2ovLlsLJUSsmgDG3nTbFgt7n8zSYYT2LkZEqLrA==", "duel"=>{"duelers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"2"}, "1"=>{"user_id"=>"15"}}, "consequence"=>"t", "reward"=>"t"}, "dueler"=>{"challenge_id"=>"141"}, "button"=>""}
```

Only one `challenge_id` is passing through although there should be two (one for each dueler). How can I get the below code to output something like this upon submit:

```
Started POST "/duels" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-15 03:33:02 -0400
Processing by DuelsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xhbQpHgBmzfuvmYsyZx1Hss8CZBfQQN9+QCEciiq4yUMmT3rZ6eH6QZbIto/6GFoodM46Ug0a1FcLlPaymBB7w==", "duel"=>{"duelers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "challenge_id"=>"141"}, "1"=>{"user_id"=>"15", "challenge_id"=>"143"}}, "consequence"=>"t", "reward"=>"t"}, "button"=>""}
```

**duels_controller**

```
  def new
    @duel = Duel.new
    @user = User.find(params[:challenge_daddy])
    @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: current_user.id, user_name: current_user.name, user_last_name: current_user.last_name)
    @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: @user.id, user_name: @user.name, user_last_name: @user.last_name)
    @current_user_challenges = current_user.challenges.order(:created_at)
    @challenged_user_challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)
    respond_with(@duel)
  end
```

**duels/new**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:duelers) do |dueler| %>
    <%= render 'dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>
  <% end %>
  The loser will <%= f.text_field :consequence %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] }, include_blank: true, id: "change-challenge-options" %>

<div id="current-user-challenges">
    <%= f.collection_select :challenge_id, @current_user_challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true %>
</div>

<div id="challenged-user-challenges">
    <%= f.collection_select :challenge_id, @challenged_user_challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true %>
</div>

<script> # If current_user then I show first collection_select otherwise I show second.
    var userSelect = $('#change-challenge-options');
    var currentUserId = $('#current-user-id').data('user-id');
    $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide();
    $('#current-user-challenges').hide();
    userSelect.on('change', function() {
      if (userSelect.val() == "0"){
         $('#current-user-challenges').hide();
         $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide();
        }
      else if (userSelect.val() == currentUserId) {
        $('#current-user-challenges').show();
        $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide();
      } else {
        $('#challenged-user-challenges').show();
        $('#current-user-challenges').hide();
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think you should get rid of those JS and try some different way, like onchange of select, make a ajax call and get the data and populate options of select. Maybe you can find a better way but seeing this JS feels like you are creating 2 select with same ID which is not HTML standard and again you are just hiding one of those select but hidden fields still submits their data on form submission.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good at JS as you can tell @sajan. Would you mind providing an answer with your suggestion? Please I beg of you good sir!

Comment: You can try first to confirm that, this is a JS issue. Remove the `script` block and `current-user-challenges` div and try to submit data with that and see if you get `params` as you have mentioned in question. If you managed to get that format params, then we can see about the JS

Comment: Yea @sajan that's exactly how I got that `params` block was by doing as you just suggested

Comment: Thats good, If it is working then only you need to create a dynamic `select` which changes `options` based on selected user id. Try to find some blogs about it in google, if you cant make it yourself or I will post a answer when I get some free time. see https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/ or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11204834/4587148, may give you an idea.

Comment: I'm trying the dynamic select boxes @sajan but now both the `collection_select` are showing for each user instead of just the respective `collection_select`, but I do think that's the right overall direction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125783/discussion-between-sajan-and-anthonygalli-com).

Comment: @sajan hey sorry I'm over at chat now if you wanna stop by :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see your params that are being sent you do indeed pass two challange ids.
One being from the challanged user and another from the challanger.

You just need to access them better in the controller and save it in the appropriate place.

```
{  
  "utf8"  =>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"  =>"...",
  "duel"  =>  {  
    "duelers_attributes"    =>    {  
      "0"      =>      {  
        "user_id"        =>"2",
        "challenge_id"        =>"141"
      },
      "1"      =>      {  
        "user_id"        =>"15",
        "challenge_id"        =>"143"
      }
    },
    "consequence"    =>"t",
    "reward"    =>"t"
  },
  "button"  =>""
}
```

I've separated the lines for easier redability, but essentially in your create or update method you can access the `duel_params["duel]["0"]["challange_id"]` and save it anywhere you would like, the same for `duel_params["duel]["1"]["challange_id"]`

You can also update one or another on an active record callback, like after_save or after_validation method, whatever works best for you

Comment: You need to add those fields to your dueler_fields form, essentially if you have anything in your form it gets passed into the params.

You will have to sanitize it through safe_params though

Comment: Name the  f.collection_select :challenge_id differently, being one for challanger and another challanged. If simple form does not allow you since challnger_id does not exist on duel, use a simple rails tag instead of simple_form

Comment: You can still pass the same challange_id to any model that you want, just capture it in that active record callback and save it to an appropriate amount of other users